# Is it possible to create database snapshots on an Azure SQL virtual machine?

Tags: sql, azure, snapshot

I was wondering if it is possible to create database snapshots on an Azure SQL virtual machine. The following query:

```
CREATE DATABASE <DB_Name>_Snapshot on (
    Name = <DB_Name>,
    filename = '\<DB_Name>.ss'
) as snapshot of <DB_Name>;
```

Gives this error:

> A database
> snapshot cannot be created because it failed to start.
>
> CREATE FILE
> encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while
> attempting to open or create the physical file
> '<DB_Name>.ss'

Normally this is a permissions issue which can be resolved by giving the SQL service account the relevant access but I can't work out if it can be done on an SQL virtual machine.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I searched and found that Azure SQL VM support create database snapshots. It depends on you SQL Server version. Ref here: [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15)

Others get the same error which all caused by you are getting a permissions error. The account which is running the SQL Server doesn't have the needed rights on the folder which will contain the database files.

**Solution:** Check file to make sure it is inheriting permissions from parent and is not owned by single user.

You ref these blogs:

1. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/08/25/sql-server-fix-create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5-access-is-denied/
2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22250/create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5-access-is-denied
3. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/vault-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/CREATE-FILE-encountered-operating-system-error-5-Access-is-denied-when-attaching-databases-in-Vault.html
4. https://sqlcan.com/2010/04/23/create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5access-is-denied/

These links can give the guides to solve the problem.